# Difference between ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN and LockType.READ?

Tags: jakarta-ee, concurrency, singleton

Compare this Java EE enterprise javabean:

```
@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
public class BMC {}
```

..with this bean:

```
@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
@Lock(LockType.READ)
public class CMC {}
```

Because container managed concurrency is the default, one can rewrite the second bean like so:

```
@Singleton
@Lock(LockType.READ)
public class CMC {}
```

Thus it makes me wonder of course. What is the difference? I can **1)** turn off container managed concurrency all together as I did in my `BMC` class, or I can **2)** use container managed concurrency but annotate the class with a read lock like I did on my `CMC` class. The `CMC` class has effectively had his container managed concurrency control turned off as long as I don't put in a write lock somewhere in the class declaration.

Can one say there is a technical difference between the two constructs I demoed? Is there any arguments why one construct would be better or preferred over the other one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [LockType.WRITE javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/LockType.html#WRITE) Using LockType.READ does create a lock. This lock allows other methods with READ locks to be executed but blocks anything with a WRITE lock from running until the READ lock is released.

There is sure to be some overhead related to creating the READ lock (possibly minimal and not noticeable) which you will not encounter unless using container managed concurrency.

Which one is better probably has different answers for different people or different circumstances or different priorities.